# Ubuntu ISO image burn to DVD not creating a Live/Bootable DVD

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, bootable-media

I have downloaded ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso[Ubuntu 11.10] and Fedora-16-i686-Live-Desktop.iso[Fedora-16] images for the respective sites. I wanted to create bootable installation dics for both these flavours. I use Win-7 Disc Image burner inbuilt in the Windows Explorer to burn these image files on to 2 separate DVD dics. But when I reboot with these discs in the DVD drive tray, neither of this starts the Fedora or Ubuntu installation process. I have set in my PC Bios Setup my DVD drive as 1st bootable drive, then my hard disk as 2nd bootable drive.

I don't udnerstand what could be going wrong here?

When I check the files burnt on the discs in Windows explorer I see as follows:

**Fedora 16 Disc:**
[image]

**Ubuntu 11.10 Disc:**
[image]

I have seen my PC boot from bootable CDs in past? I doubt if the files are burnt correctly?

What could be going wrong here? Any help?

PS - When we insert a blank DVD in the tray, and select Burn Image menu, by default there was a file named desktop.ini present , which I did not burn on the DVDs in both cases. What is that file? Could that file also be needed to be burnt along with the Image files ?

Answer (score 1):

seems to me like windows extracts the iso, then burns the files, rather then directly the iso. try burning with deepburner. it's free and should do anything fancy.

Comment: I guess thats how it should be right. Extract ISO files and then burn. I even tried simply buring the *.iso directly to DVD. Even then same result, no booting done by DVD.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a program that can directly burn the ISO to disk, then that is what you want to use. I've used a program called [ISO Recorder 3.1](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/W7.htm) frequently to burn disk images. If you install it, simply put the proper disk into your burner, then right click the .ISO file and select the "Copy image to CD/DVD" option.

If the resulting disk won't boot, I would suspect the drive itself. In that case you may want to look around for a firmware upgrade for that model. I've seen issues in the past where some bootable CD's would work and others wouldn't, I'm not entirely sure of the reason, but a firmware upgrade may help. This is a likely culprit if your drive is pretty old, not so much if it is new.

Comment: I don't think the drive's firmware has anything to do with being able to boot from CD or DVD.  An El Torito boot record is just ordinary data; all the drive has to do is read the sectors that the BIOS asks it to.

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problem as well.  My solution was to open Windows explorer in Windows 7 and double click on the *.iso file.  This will open a windows application called "Windows Disc Image Burner".  Result is you get a bootable CD or DVD.

Hope this helps future users.  Randy

Comment: This is **exactly** what the author did and claims did not work.